# How to properly write spring-security.xml file?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm new to spring security and I'm trying to apply it to a working spring-mvc project.
The error is:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict,
but no declaration can be found for element http.
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"      
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<http auto-config='true'>
 <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
 <authentication-provider>
  <user-service>
    <user name="matt3o" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
  </user-service>
</authentication-provider>
```

I have added spring-security dependency in pom.xml.

If I delete

```
<http auto-config='true'>
 <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
```

the error is the same but:

```
no declaration can be found for element authentication-manager.
```

it looks like namespaces are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your default namespace for the xml is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` but it should be `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security`. Also you have to add the following in the `xsi:schemaLocation`

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
```

And you have to configure how the user provide the credentials. The easiest ones are

1. Form based login

   User uses a html form to enter credentials. To use form login put `<form-login />` inside `<http>` tag, which gives you default login page which can be replaces by your own later.
2. Basic authentication.

   User uses the browser's login dialog. To use basic put `<http-basic />` inside `<http>` tag.

So your final `spring-security.xml`should be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"      
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


  <http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/logged" access="ROLE_USER"/> 
    <!-- Replace the below with http-basic tag for basic authentication -->
    <form-login/>
  </http>    

  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="matt3o" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**Note**: Don't forget to add spring-security-config.jar in classpath.

Comment: ok. thank you. Do I need also some configuration for the "http" line?

Comment: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element http. seems the first problem is solved.

Comment: You've to add spring-security-config.jar in class path

Comment: Yes I did. I added the dependency in pom.xml